# Term for a particular or general skill that needs to be improved and acted on?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a particular or general skill, possibly part of a skill-set, that needs to be improved and acted on?

It's at the tip of my tongue... I don't think it would be "*incapabilities*", or "*deficiencies*"; it's something more precise than that.

Comment: Area (or skill) needing improvement.

Comment: thanks Drew. But my question is, is there a specific term that actually relates it?

Comment: The question is a bit oxymoronic. I know what you mean, but I can't think of a word for it.

Comment: However, a "skill" is something at which you have aptitude, whereas "needing improvement" implies the exact opposite.

Comment: In a sporting context "weakness" seems quite common. e.g. "Use your off season to work on your weaknesses"

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish that is quite a point you have. Hmm..I was thinking of writing an essay where "working with a mentor, will turn these faults-inabilities into their opposites." along those lines. Just cant seem to find the proper term or correct way to write the statement lol

Comment: @Triplexriku Perhaps "short-comings?"

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish  I like that one, but still wouldn't really acknowledge them with that term use

Comment: @Triplexriku Shakespeare would probably just fabricate a word. How about improwess? Aptitusion?

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish haha! You're awesome. You were a big help, any of those would suffice. Now If only i knew what to do with this thread. :)

Comment: @Martin Smith Expand on your comment (e.g., reference, sample sentence) and turn it into an answer!  It is the right word.

Comment: @MartinSmith He has a point but I wouldnt necessarily say it's a weakness, as it has not been developed.

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish  the word  i was looking for was "shortcoming". Came across it today, coincidentally.

Comment: That's what I suggested about 6 comments ago XD

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish LOL I must have misinterpreted the term by chance

Comment: _"Competencies"_ or _"initial skills"_ _**allow**_  for improvement, they do not necessarily "need" it...

Answer (score -1):

Ineptitude, inept

The inability to do something well. Not good at something.

Example:

He is great at painting but has the following ineptitudes: clay modelling, drawing, and pen and ink.

Or, He is marvellous at arimethmetic but inept at calculus and equations.

Link to synonyms for Lack of Skill:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/lack-of-skill-or-ability

Comment: This suggests something entirely lacking, not something with room for further improvement.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of its meaning of 'lacking in fitness or aptitude' https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inept