# Something that needs to be refreshed

Tags: single-word-requests

An expert of older times whose skills have **regressed** is:

- rusty;
- out of practice;
- formerly skilled;
- semi-skilled;
- in need of training;
- erstwhile expert;
- veteran beginner;
- false beginner;
- remedial learner.

His *skill in question is **antiquated***. I'm looking for a better adjective to state that a skill needs to be refreshed.

For example: I'm *out of practice* of cooking. (I apologize for the poor sentence. It is the problem exactly).

---

I've already seen [this similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293686/a-term-for-a-particular-or-general-skill-that-needs-to-be-improved-and-acted-on) that does not have an answer.

Comment: PS: Need a word that I can write in my resume.

Comment: "Stale" is the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: @HotLicks: I see you have taken the antonym route. But saying in my resume that my skills are _stale_ doesn't sound very positive. I'm assured that I can get to a professional level in reasonable time. Need a positive or neutral word.

Comment: Why use a word at all?  Just put: "3 years C++ experience (2003-2006)" or whatever.

Comment: There is a difference between "rusty", meaning you've not "exercised" that "muscle" for awhile, and "not current", meaning you need to bone up on the last three versions of OSx or whatever.

Comment: @Jim: Problem arises when C++ is not the only skill that needs such mentioning. Takes up a lot of space to stay consistent and do the same for every such skill. Want to compartmentalize all the skills that need refresher.

Comment: @HotLicks: How to say that I *will have to bone up on W, X, Y and Z* by using a single word?

Comment: Familiar with x,y, and z.  Some experience with x,y, and z.

Comment: @Jim: Nah.. I'm not just familiar. I was very proficient in X, Y and Z. I just need to catch up with the advancements.

Comment: Then don't say you're rusty.  Just put the experience.  If it's important it'll come up in the interview.  Because you do expect that if you get the job you're going to do what it takes to come back up to speed without impacting the project's schedule right?

Comment: Don't fixate on using a single word.  Tell them you have skills X, Y, and Z that were current is 1842, and you simply need to make them current.

Comment: I don't think you can find a word to say your skills are out-of-date in a positive way. Instead, as others have alluded, something like "Highly proficient in previous versions of C++." And, of course, focus on projects, outcomes and more general timeless skills.

Comment: I assume you have a section at the top of your resume with keywords: C/C++, bash, lex/yacc, Matlab  etc.  Then you have reverse order company listings where you say, "Developed such and such in C".  If you do then people can see your recency of experience because they will find that lex and yacc aren't listed until you get back to your job in 1997.

Comment: Hot Licks and Jim's comments are the most sensible suggestions. Your potential employers will figure out for themselves that you'll need a little time in order for your skills to be *upgraded* and *in line* with the most current or latest developments. "Up to speed" I think sounds appropriate http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed

Comment: This WSJ article seems tailor made to your situation http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052970204422404576596630897409182

Comment: It should be pointed out that, in today's computer biz, anyone who's out of it for even 3 weeks falls behind.  It's hard enough for people who work in it every day to stay current.  If the potential employer does not understand this they aren't going to be a good place to work (for very long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not **rusty** itself?

It is not just a person that can get a bit rusty, but also the skill.

Google "my" + "is a bit rusty" and there are many examples, e.g., "My French is a bit rusty".

Answer (score 1):

You need to **bone up** on your cooking skills.

> 2 :  to renew one's skill or refresh one's memory

"Bone up." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 16 Mar. 2016.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm looking for a word to write in my resume. Can't "bone-up" there. :D

Answer (score 1):

How about **[rejuvenate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rejuvenate)**:

"When you make something young again or give it more life and energy"

"You could rejuvenate your cooking skills by attending cooking courses."

Or

You could use rejuvenation/rejuvenating.

"After the rejuvenation of my cooking skills, cooking seemed easier."

Answer (score 1):

You could say that your cooking skills have *lapsed*.

This is a figurative use of the term, whose literal definition relates to expiry dates:

> **Lapse** *adjective*
>   No longer valid; expired
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lapsed)

Here are some examples from the internet:

- It must be stated most of the group had already been introduced to code at an earlier date and had not stayed with it and their skill had lapsed. - [Tom EI5CA](http://www.themorsecrusade.g5fz.co.uk/2012/01/limerick-radio-club-morse-practice-report/)
- I still solve a ton of crosswords, so I have no reason to think my clue-solving skill has lapsed. - [That Puzzle Guy's Blog](http://www.tylerhinman.com/blog/posts/1185)
- Perhaps, when a composer succeeds, one hears only beautiful music; but when a composer's skill has lapsed, one hears the symptoms of human effort and human weakness. - [Nicole Grimes et al, "Rethinking Hanslick: Music, Formalism, and Expression"](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=rxMC12Pr5RkC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%22skill%20has%20lapsed%22&source=bl&ots=StKMPi2OLv&sig=ayq8NIqbGIIdYMTU44gIxtRBP_k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9it6JmsfLAhXEFJQKHUqYCOoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22skill%20has%20lapsed%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [***unimproved***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unimproved?searchDictCode=all):

> **unimproved**
>
> Not made better:
> *the living standards of the majority of Bulgarians has remained unimproved*

It suggests that improvement is possible, but not carried out yet. So your sentence becomes:

> My skill in cooking is *unimproved*.

<sub>Note, BTW, that this adjective [has been mainly used for lands and roads](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+unimproved%22#q=%22is+unimproved%22&tbm=bks&start=20).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

> . Workers in manufacturing positions need **(1)retraining** to learn new work processes or new computerised equipment.
>
> . While these skills should be **(1)retrained** every three years or more, many individuals seldom get an opportunity to practice what they have learned.

and

> . Employers can either retrain late career workers and **(2)adjust** their skills to the new needs of the workplace.
>
> . Smarter Parenting skills should be **(2)adjusted** and used in a way that will be most helpful to children with Reactive attachment disorder (RAD)

Answer (score 0):

I think single word answers will be either sounding strange or rarely in use.

How about these?

I understand that you're experienced in a particular field, but [**out of touch**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+touch) with it lately.

> not informed about something
>
> *"The report shows that the committee is **out of touch** with recent developments in space technology."*

So you just need to get [**in touch**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+touch) with the latest versions.

> having recent knowledge about something
>
> *"I try to keep **in touch** with the latest developments in the music scene."*
>
> *"A president must stay **in touch** to know what citizens want or need.*"

In my humble opinion, it's never good to mention that your skills are [**outdated**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outdated).

What's better is to say that you're experienced in those fields, but will need to [**update**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/update) yourself on the recent developments.

> to tell someone the latest news about someone or something.
>
> *"Please **update me** about the current situation in France."*
>
> *"Please **update me** about Tony."*